# Determine if this series $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^6+13n^5+n+1}{n^7+13n^4+9n+2}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine if the following series converges:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{n^6+13n^5+n+1}{n^7+13n^4+9n+2}.
$$

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWiuy.png)

I don't know how to  start.

Comment: When $n$ is big,  the thing is $\frac{1}{n}$-ish. Limit Comparison with $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 5):

Use the limit comparison test.

Let $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{n^6+13n^5+n+1}{n^7+13n^4+9n+2}$ and $\displaystyle b_n=\frac{n^6}{n^7}=\frac{1}{n}$.

Since

$$\begin{align}\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^6+13n^5+n+1}{n^7+13n^4+9n+2}\cdot\frac{n}{1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^7\left(1+13\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^5}+\frac{1}{n^7}\right)}{n^7\left(1+13\frac{1}{n^3}+9\frac{1}{n^6}+\frac{2}{n^7}\right)} \\
&=1 > 0 \end{align}$$

Both $a_n$ and $b_n$ converges or diverges. Since $b_n$ diverges, so too must $a_n$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** You have, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{n^6+13n^5+n+1}{n^7+13n^4+9n+2} = \frac1n+\mathcal{O}{\left(\frac1{n^2} \right)}
$$ thus, by the comparison test, the initial series is **divergent**.

Comment: I have a feeling OP isn't familiar with $\mathcal{O}$ notation.

Comment: @PhilipHoskins Here it just means that there is a constant $C$ such that $\left|u_n-\frac1n\right|\leq \frac{C}{n^2}$, as $n \to \infty$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a comparison test. Remember with series that you can disregard a finite number of terms. When $n \geq 2$

$$n^7+13n^5+9n+2 \leq n^7 +13n^7 + 9n^7+n^2 = 24n^7,$$

which implies

$$ \frac{1}{n^7+13n^5+9n+2} \geq \frac{1}{n^7 +13n^7 + 9n^7+n^2} \geq \frac{1}{24n^7}.$$

For the numerator, you have

$$n^6 + 13n^5 + n + 1 \geq n^6.$$

Therefore

$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^6 + 13n^5 + n + 1}{n^6 + 13n^5 + 9n + 2} \geq \frac{1}{24} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^6}{n^7} = \frac{1}{24}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n} =\infty, $$

which shows that the series diverges by comparison with the harmonic series.

Comment: I think this is honestly the best answer considering the OP's (probable) level of experience.